# Trouble decomposing to 3rd Normal Form (DB)

Tags: database, database-normalization, decomposition, third-normal-form

I've recently started studying Data Bases but I'm struggling with this specific part.

I've read the definition of each `Normal Form` but I still can't seem to understand. Here's an example that I couldn't solve properly:

```
**R(A,B,C,D,E,F)**
A->B; B->CD; AD->E
```

Solution: `R1(*A*,B,E); R2(*B*,C,D); R3(*A*,*F*)`

I can't understand why the `R3` is like that

Comment: What can you understand? Like what? Please show your solution with justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R3 is to make sure it is in 2nd Normal Form and there is no update anomaly. F in R1 would lead to duplicate rows of A,B,E where there are multiple F values for A. B and E values might be either ambiguous or completely redundant.